# Trying to make @ tag for usernames

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I tried to use preg_replace to make @ to tag usernames in my php game.

Here is my code:

```
$find[13] = '@';
$replace[13] = '<a href="profil.php?username=$1">';

return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
```

I only get this warning message:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '@' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mafiagamev2\functions\bbcodes.php on line 61
```

Any help?

Comment: `preg_replace()` is not `str_replace()`. The former requires a regular expression. The latter requires a simple static string.

Comment: `preg_replace('/@/',`

Comment: I see.. But then again to get the input, how shall the /@/ look like?
I have on my BB-codes: '~\[ytb\](.*?)\[/ytb\]~s';
Then I use .*?, but when I write this on my @ it won't work.
Like this: '/@.*?/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `preg_replace()` requires a regular expression as search string. Most programming languages have a regex type, but not PHP. Here you define a pattern as string with delimiters enclosing the pattern. You can basically use most alphanumeric characters, including `@`, but the most commonly used is `/`. So `preg_replace` expects a pattern enclosed in delimiters and you provided only one character, which PHP interprets as the opening delimiter.

What you want to do is to replace all words that start with an `@` with the link. A lot of this regex depends on how you validate usernames. For this example I am assuming you only allow upper- and lowercase alphanumeric characters, numbers, hyphen and underscore:

```
preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([\w\d-_]+)/g', '<a href="profil.php?username=$2">$2</a>')
```

[Get the explanation and try it out](https://regex101.com/r/AYpxbL/3)

Note that you might generate a lot of dead links. I suggest validating with JavaScript during the input or validating the usernames to replace against your database.

Comment: This get's me closer to a solution! But when I for example write @ username
It echo's @ username and then the link becomes profil.php?username=@ username. Is there any way that the @ don't become echo'd so that I get redirected to the link profil.php?username=username ?

Comment: ah, sure. My mistake. You just have to move the opening bracket for the match to the right of the @ sing, so it won't be included in the match. I updated the answer.